# batch - how can I close a batch file that was started from another batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a problem understanding how I can automatically close a batch file that was started from another batch file.

My first batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off

:logs
start C:\Users\Kenturrac\Desktop\copy.bat

timeout 2

goto logs
```

So as you can see there, I start another batch file called "copy.bat" which looks like that:

```
::set arma path
@set ARMAPATH=C:\Users\Administrator.WIN-B8I65OIU3DJ\Desktop\server\dayz_epoch_1

::set log path
@set LOGPATH=%ARMAPATH%\_LOGS
@set MOVEORCOPY=copy


:: Berechne Zeitstempel
@set DAY=%DATE:~0,2%
@set MONTH=%DATE:~3,2%
@set YEAR=%DATE:~6,4%
@set DATE=%YEAR%_%MONTH%_%DAY%

@set HH=%TIME:~0,2%
@IF "%TIME:~0,1%"==" " (
    set HH=0%TIME:~1,1%
)
@set MIN=%TIME:~3,2%
@set SEC=%TIME:~6,2%
@set TIME=%HH%%MIN%

@IF NOT EXIST "%LOGPATH%\%DATE%_%TIME%\" (
    @set TEMPPATH=%DATE%_-_%TIME%
) ELSE ( 
    @set TEMPPATH=%DATE%_-_%TIME%_%SEC%
)

@set TARGETPATH=%LOGPATH%\%TEMPPATH%\
@echo %TARGETPATH%

Exit /b
```

The problem is that it doesn't close the additional cmd window it started for the "copy.bat".
If I use "call" instead of "start", it will mess up the "temppath" variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the second batch file does something more than setting environment variables to values that will be discarded as the batch file is started in a new process, and if the only concern not to use `call` instead of `start` is the protection of the values of the variables in the first process, use `setlocal / endlocal` instructions in the second batch to avoid the problem of file close and the interference in the values of the variables.

Comment: after setting the vars in the second batchfile it continues with copying files. Didn't seem important here so I skipped that part. But yeah, setlocal / endlocal works fine with the call command. thx for that! Can you explain to me why he is not closing the window if I use the start command since I am using a exit at the end of the second batch file.

Comment: Try using `@echo off` at the beginning.